# Ag-grid-pin first row in pivot

Tags: ag-grid

I have a pivot in Aggrid in which I need to pin the top row, i have tried using

```
getRowStyle:function(params) {
                const rowNode = params.node;
                //console.log(rowNode,'row node')
                // Conditionally pin rows based on row value
                if (rowNode && rowNode.field === 'GrandTotal') {
                  return { 'position': 'sticky', 'top': '0','background':'red' };
                }
            
                // Return null to apply default styling
                return null;
            },
```

Now this top row is getting styled but it is not sticky
[image]